# Custom configurations in Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am converting an Azure webjob to an Azure function. The webjob uses a custom configuration, added as a configuration section in app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
             <section name="cacheSettings" type="Common.Configuration.CacheSettings, Common" restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
        </configSections>
    </configuration>
```

Is there any way that I can deploy a configuration with the Azure function?

Comment: There is no such thing but what is your custom section for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in Azure Functions. Whatever values you're initializing through app.config will have to be initialized through code instead of configuration.